# if runs without checking else if

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm using node.js with discord.js to create a private chatbot for a server.

I have this code for a command to define who you're at war with.

I get this error if in discord i run "!war" on its own:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

What's happened to else if?

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "war")) {
  let [name] = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1);
  if (name.length < 16) {
    war[id[msg.author.id]] = name;
    msg.channel.send("You are now at war with **" + name + "**. Use !pp for war info.");
    console.log("Command executed : !war");
    fs.writeFile('war.json', JSON.stringify(war));
  } else if (name.isNaN) {
    msg.channel.send("Enter something.");
  } else {
    msg.channel.send("Enter something with less than 16 characters.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Uh, `isNaN` is generally a function, called like `isNaN(name)`. One does wonder when an array, which `name` is, ever becomes a number ?

Comment: Also, it should probably be `let name = ...`

Comment: Yeah, i was using it incorrectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (name.length < 16)
```

It is trying to evaluate name.length and fails here.
I suggest you write

```
  if(name!=undefined && name.length && name.length<16)
```

Answer (score 0):

First check for undefined values and exit function if that is the case, then do some work if input is valid. If is performed before else if in your case so it throws an Exception